# Storing user data (settings) in separate table to speed up user search

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

If a web application has to search many IDs to find a matching on, but doesn't need any user data until the correct one has been found, would it be optimal to store the user data fields in a separate table and use the Accounts table (which contains user ID, password hash, etc.) for searches?

Answer (score 1):

Create a clustered index on your unique ID field which will determine the physical ordering of data and it will speed up the searches and then you can extract only the required rows.

You can also create a non clustered index and then make it point to the primary key.